# Getting this error: Attempted import error: 'userReducer' is not exported from '../features/user/userSlice'

Tags: reactjs

When compiled i am getting this error:
Attempted import error: 'userReducer' is not exported from '../features/user/userSlice'.

i dont know why Please Help !!!

Importing in Header.js

```
import { userReducer } from "../features/user/userSlice";
```

This is the userSlice.js

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

   const initialState = {
     name: "",
     email: "",
     photo: "",
   };

   

    const userSlice = createSlice({
         name: "user",
         initialState,
         reducers: {
            setUserLoginDetails: (state, action) => {
              state.name = action.payload.name;
              state.email = action.payload.email;
              state.photo = action.payload.photo;
            }, 

        setSignOutState: (state) => {
          state.name = null;
          state.email = null;
          state.photo = null;
        },
      },
    
        });

    export const { setUserLoginDetails, setSignOutState } = userSlice.actions;
    
    export const selectUserName = (state) => state.user.name;
    export const selectUserEmail = (state) => state.user.email;
    export const selectUserPhoto = (state) => state.user.photo;
    
    export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any named export in userSlice.js called `userReducer`. I am assuming you want to import the `userSlice.reducer`. You have two options, either:

- Replace your import to import the default export as follow (in Header.js):

```
import userReducer from "../features/user/userSlice";
```

- **Or** export the reducer as a named export as follow (in userSlice.js):

```
export const userReducer = userSlice.reducer;
```